# Has anyone tried using Parrot Mini drone (rolling spider) with ROS?

Tags: ros, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am thinking of buying the parrot mini drone to do some flight by sending twist messages from ROS. I want to know if someone has a working package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208862/has-anyone-tried-using-parrot-mini-drone-(rolling-spider)-with-ros?/) by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [this other thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/214244/is-ros-compatible-with-parrots-mini-drones-like-rolling-spider-and-jumping-sumo/).

---

Originally posted by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) with karma: 101 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0